# Android RxJava2 retryWhen usage not compiling

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

Trying to add retry to an RxJava2 retrofit2 call in Kotlin, however, cannot figure out the right syntax.

Did some research and found that I need to use retryWhen using pattern like (for retrying 3 times):

```
val api: Single<Item> = ...;
api
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
   .retryWhen {errors ->
            errors
                .zipWith(Observable.range(1, 3), { index: Int -> {} })
                .flatMap {
                    count: Int -> Observable.timer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                }
        }
   .subscribe { }
```

But with this I get various build errors:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:

@CheckReturnValue @BackpressureSupport @SchedulerSupport public final fun <U : Any!, R : Any!> zipWith(p0: ((Subscriber<in (???..???)>!) -> Unit)!, p1: ((Throwable, ???) -> ???)!): Flowable<(???..???)>! defined in io.reactivex.Flowable
@CheckReturnValue @BackpressureSupport @SchedulerSupport public final fun <U : Any!, R : Any!> zipWith(p0: (Mutable)Iterable<(???..???)>!, p1: ((Throwable, ???) -> ???)!): Flowable<(???..???)>! defined in io.reactivex.Flowable
@CheckReturnValue @BackpressureSupport @SchedulerSupport public final fun <U : Any!, R : Any!> zipWith(p0: (Mutable)Iterable<(???..???)>!, p1: BiFunction<in Throwable!, in (???..???), out (???..???)>!): Flowable<(???..???)>! defined in io.reactivex.Flowable
@CheckReturnValue @BackpressureSupport @SchedulerSupport public final fun <U : Any!, R : Any!> zipWith(p0: Publisher<out (???..???)>!, p1: BiFunction<in Throwable!, in (???..???), out (???..???)>!): Flowable<(???..???)>! defined in io.reactivex.Flowable
```

What I am missing or doing wrong? I am not able to find good tutorial that I can go through to understand this better?

Comment: I think you need to explicitly call `Bifunction`

Answer (score 2):

You have to make a change in your `zipWith` operator to use `BiFunction` like this:

```
.zipWith(Observable.range(1, 3), BiFunction { error: Throwable, index: Int -> index })
```

As you can see in your build errors, you have to provide `Throwable` as first parameter in `BiFunction`.